# Работа с строками, символами. Выдает ошибку ( c++ )

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, функции, символы

Я ввожу фамилию, имя, отчество как одну строку символов. Узнал длину строки, а также количество букв Q1. Надо сделать 2-я методами: 
 1. Используя функции с библиотек.
 2. Рассматривая строку как массив символов.
Задание: Вывести строку без букв А и О (на английском). Узнать количество букв в фамилии.
Выдает вот такую ошибку - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmDEx.jpg .
И не могу понять как найти количество букв в фамилии, помогите пожалуйста, или хотя-бы намекните что, как.. Заранее спасибо! 
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string Q1,name,name2;
    int quan=0; // количество
    char A='A'; // поиск символа А
    cout<<"surname name and father: ";
    getline(cin,Q1);
    cout<<Q1.size()<<endl;
   for(int i=0;i<Q1.size();++i)
    {
        Q1.erase(Q1.find('A'), 1);
        Q1.erase(Q1.find('O'), 1);


    }

    cout << Q1;



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
//введите сначала имя, а потом фамилию через пробел
getline(cin,Q1);
name2 = Q1.substr(Q1.find(' ') + 1);//фамилия
cout << name2.size() << endl;

// удаление 'A'
while(Q1.find('A') != string::npos) {
    Q1.erase(Q1.find('A'), 1);
}
// удаление 'O'
while(Q1.find('O') != string::npos) {
    Q1.erase(Q1.find('O'), 1);
}

cout << Q1 << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, компилятор предупредил, что у вас есть неиспользуемые переменные.

А слет программы - так ведь если искомой буквы нет - что получится? `Q1.find('O')` будет указывать куда-то вне программы, а вы его на удаление... Проверяйте, что возвращает `.find()`.

И непонятно, зачем вы это удаление повторяете `Q1.size()` раз?